# Javascript: Add to string until ready for display

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm using this function to read all the information out of my IndexedDb logStore (yes the variables are set correctly)

When I call the function, and it displays the result, all I get are the first two rows of the table I defined.  The if (cursor) {} snippet won't place any output into the table, however the alert()'s display all the information until there's no more data in the store.

Does anyone have suggestions as to making the data come into the table?

```
function readLog() {
// TODO: Make strings concatenate
var objectStore = db.transaction(logStore).objectStore(logStore);

    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {

      content = '<table border="1" width="50%"><tr><td width="10%">Event ID</td><td width="10%">Timestamp</td><td width="80%">Message</td></tr>'; // Works
      content += "<tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr>"; // Works

      var cursor = event.target.result;

      if (cursor) {
            content.concat("<tr><td>" + cursor.key + "</td><td>" + cursor.value.timestamp + "</td><td>" + cursor.value.message + "</td></tr>"); // Doesn't work
            alert("ID: " + cursor.key + " TS: " + cursor.value.timestamp + " Message: " + cursor.value.message); // Works
            cursor.continue();
      }
      else {
            content.concat("</table>");
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=content;
      }
    };      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`concat()` returns a new array comprised of this array joined with other array(s) and/or value(s). You should be writing something like `content = content.concat(...)` or you can use `+=` like you did with the first string concatenation.